# Detect page refresh, but not the ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, onbeforeunload

I programmed an ajax file upload. After ajax is done a popup occur where the uploaded image is displayed. In this popup I can crop an area to get a thumbnail of the picture.

The problem is that if I refresh the page before I crop the image the Crop-Function won't run and I don't get the thumbnail.

For this reason I tried the following, after the ajax return is true:

```
// If page refresh, run the Crop-Function
window.unload = cropImage();
```

But if the data will be send to the server and the server sends some data back `$(window).onbeforeunload` already runs. Do you have any ideas to solve that problem?

Comment: On page refresh, the function will be reinitialized right? Then there is no use to detect in page refresh.

Comment: The function is called when I click on a Crop-Button. But if I click on the Page-Refresh-Button in the browser, I can bypass the function. But I don't want that this is possible.

Comment: @Exploson Pills 
I mean if I send the data to the server and get some data back, the function already runs

Comment: `$.fn.onbeforeunload` doesn't exist.